# Karate test follows 303 dummy URL when `Expires: 0` header is missing

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, karate

I have a Karate test that sends a POST that then will send back a redirect to a dummy address.  With a recent Spring upgrade, I am now seeing the redirect coming back as a `303` rather than a `302`.

I do not want this `302` URL to be followed with a request.  The test just verified that we got a `302` back, and continued with more validation.  This is what I have been seeing up until the Spring upgrade.  However, with the `303` returned, it is then followed by a `GET` request to the dummy URL, which then fails with an `UnknownHostException`.  I think perhaps due to the presence of `Expires: 0` in the headers of the `302`.  The 303 does not contain this header (or `Pragma: no-cache` but I can't see how that would affect it).  Below are the reponse headers for each, with differences highlighted with `*`

**302**

```
  5 < 302
* 5 < Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
  5 < Connection: keep-alive
  5 < Content-Language: en-US
  5 < Content-Length: 0
  5 < Date: Mon, 16 Mar 2020 12:04:55 GMT
* 5 < Expires: 0
  5 < Location: http://anywhere?key=value&code=iXAnzC
* 5 < Pragma: no-cache
  5 < Server: nginx/1.17.9
  5 < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
  5 < X-Frame-Options: DENY
  5 < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

**303**

```
5 < 303
5 < Cache-Control: no-store
5 < Connection: keep-alive
5 < Content-Language: en-US
5 < Content-Length: 0
5 < Date: Fri, 13 Mar 2020 11:06:31 GMT
5 < Location: http://anywhere?key=value&code=05O7lL
5 < Server: nginx/1.17.9
5 < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
5 < X-Frame-Options: DENY
5 < X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

We do not explicitly set these headers so it will be Tomcat/NGinx behaviour, which means it's going to be standard on many servers.  Is this generally expected behaviour with `303`'s or is this related to the differences in the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you look at the `configure followRedirects` option: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configure - but I guess you know this already and maybe that works only for 302-s.

If you have already set that to `false` and still see Karate make the second call automatically, it may need a fix. Any pointers to what changes we need to make in the `karate-apache` code will help, here is the implementation for [`followRedirects`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/commit/32744d01bb78c3bb24ad33efc4f424bc0cdcc9a8).

You can also try switch to `karate-jersey` and see if that client works the way you expect.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for the response.  I tried the `karate-jersey` but couldn't get that to work.  However, I discovered that I can add `configure followRedirects = false` per request, whereas before I thought it was only at the `Scenario` level.  Adding it just before the request that causes the `303` fixes my issue!  Thanks again.